# Does Strophe js connection object have a roster property or is it a pluggin that I need to download?

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I have been following [this example](https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/articles/chat-application) to get a list of contacts using strophe. But it says roster is undefined. My guess is that it is a pluggin I need? Which one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the roster plugin. You can get it here:

https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins